# Using `ProblemDetails` with an action carrying `[Produces("application/xml")]` in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I am intending to use `ProblemDetails` and inherited classes to express 422 errors.

I created a dummy controller class and a single action in ASP.NET Core 2.2:

```
[Route("api/v1")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("values/json")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity)]
    public ActionResult JsonGet()
    {
        var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails();
        return UnprocessableEntity(problemDetails);
    }

    [HttpGet("values/xml")]
    [Produces("application/xml")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity)]
    public ActionResult XmlGet()
    {
        var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails();
        return UnprocessableEntity(problemDetails);
    }
}
```

But when hitting the API on respectively:

The json endpoint:

```
λ  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://localhost:5001/api/v1/values/json" -Headers @{'Accept' = 'application/json'; }  
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.                               
At line:1 char:1                                                                                                   
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://localhost:5001/api/v1/values/json" -H ...                                        
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                            
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], W  
   ebException                                                                                                     
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

and

The xml endpoint:

```
λ  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://localhost:5001/api/v1/values/xml" -Headers @{'Accept' = 'application/xml'; }
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://localhost:5001/api/v1/values/xml" -He ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], W
   ebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: A 406 HTTP status means that if a web server detects that the data it wants to return is not acceptable to the client, it returns a header containing the 406 error code. The client in this case needs to define the characteristics of the data it will accept back from the web server by using the accept headers

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee I am using Swagger to test the API. The accept header is hence properly set when playing with the api, still at the moment of returning the result in the action and depending if I set json or xml it returns 422 or 406.

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that was fairly stupid...

It turns out that I thought the XML support was out of the box, but that was not the case: 
https://andrewlock.net/formatting-response-data-as-xml-or-json-based-on-the-url-in-asp-net-core/

My `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info {Title = "C# Web API", Version = "v1"});
            var assemblyXmlPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, assemblyXmlPath);
            options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters(); // <= this was missing...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseSwagger()
           .UseSwaggerUI(options => options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1"));

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Now everything is on par for both endpoints:

```bsh
λ  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://localhost:5001/api/v1/values/json" -Headers @{'Accept' = 'application/json'; }
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://localhost:5001/api/v1/values/json" -H ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], W
   ebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

```bsh
λ  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://localhost:5001/api/v1/values/xml" -Headers @{'Accept' = 'application/xml'; }
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://localhost:5001/api/v1/values/xml" -He ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], W
   ebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I think the error is kinda misleading or confusing it makes you think that the issue comes from the controller / action configuration instead of services configuration.